# PHP - Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '='

Tags: php, syntax

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=' in C:\xampp\htdocs\proje\admin\Ayarlar\baglan.php on line 3

```
<?php
try{
  $Baglan = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=webing;charset=UTF8", "root", "");
}catch(PDOException $Hata){
   echo "bağlantı hatası" . $Hata->getmessage();
}
?>
```

Comment: Can you share the contents of the baglan.php file? That's where the error is coming from.

Comment: There must be something else that you're not showing or hidden character etc. https://3v4l.org/C4hnc